# Fluid mechanics : find the abs. pressure in mil. of Hg

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics, fluid-dynamics

> Problem: A vacuum of $25\, kPa$ is measured at a location where the elevation is $3000\, m$. What is the absolute pressure in millimeters of mercury?

Solution:
Through interpolation, $P_{atm} = 70.7\, kPa.$

My question is here: From the equation: 
$$P_{abs} = P_{gage} + P_{atm} = -25 + 70.7 = 45.7\, kPa,$$
Why is it $-25$ and not merely $25$?

Comment: I imagine because it is a *vacuum* of 25 kPa, which should have opposite sign of the positive pressure of the atmosphere.

Answer (score 2):

Gage pressure readings are taken assuming that $0$ gage pressure = $1$ atmosphere.
By specifying a vacuum of $25~\textrm {kPa}$, that suggests that the gage pressure is $25~\textrm {kPa}$ lower than local atmospheric.  When you want to find absolute pressure, then $P_{abs} = P_{atm} + P_{vac} = 70.7 - 25 = 45.7~\textrm {kPa}$.